# How to delete custom child theme in magento2

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme, remove

I clone my theme to set child theme. I deleted child theme folders in app/design/frontend/ and app/code//ThemeOptions/fixtures but in admin backend it's not removed. I flush cache , Please let me know how to remove my custom child theme.

Comment: Delete entry from theme table.

Comment: i tried it shows error "Theme isn't deletable."

Answer (score 0):

You can try  this  :

```
mysql -u <user> -p -e "delete from <dbname>.theme where theme_path ='<Vendor>/<theme>' AND area ='frontend' limit 1"
```

Reference from  :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-uninstall.html

Comment: can i delete using SSH.?

Comment: Yes , you can  read  the  reference as well , check  manual  deletion  step  and  follow .

Answer (score 0):

## 1. login via SSH and execute:

```
php bin/magento theme:uninstall frontend/your/theme && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

## 2. open the database and open the table "theme" and delete the theme entry.

## 3. execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE "%theme_id%"
```

And set the value to "1" to reset to "Magento Base" Theme.

Now you should be able to change your theme in the backend in "**Content -> Design -> Configuration**"

## 4. Flush cache again

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```